# Kryo vs Encoder vs Java Serialization in Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, serialization, encoder, kryo

Which serialization is used for which case, 
From spark documentation it says :
It provides two serialization libraries:
1. Java(default) and 
2. Kryo
Now where did Encoders come from and why is it not given in the doc. 
And also from databricks it says Encoders performs faster for Datasets,what about RDD, and how do all these maps together. 
In which case which serializer should we use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `Encoders` are used in `Dataset` only.
- `Kryo` is used internally in
  spark.
- `Kryo` and `Java` serialization is available for you to use
  for your data shuffling.

As to which should you use - `Kryo` is your best option if you don't use `Dataset`. Otherwise you don't have any options, actually.

Comment: But is it right that encoders use kryo internally?

Comment: are encoders used only to convert JVM objects to spark sql internal representation? As per above then, Kryo and Java serialization are used for data shuffling and not the encoders. Is my understanding right?